# XSLT Transformation .Net

Tags: .net, xslt

I am looking for a free tool in .net(I use VWD express edition), where I can see the output of a xslt transform. I can open a xsltfile, and set the input and output xmls, however, not able to run the same. I just need to see the output, even if debugging is not there, it is fine.

Not sure if i can use msxsl.exe. I heard about it that we can use that free tool for transformation. It would be great if someone can guide me.

Comment: Can you not just use `XslCompiledTransform`, feed it the source, and write to `Console` or a `StringWriter`?

Comment: msxsl works fine for me.
You can also insert a instruction in the XML source - works fine locally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use the .NET command-line utility [nxslt.exe](http://xmlwriter.net/user_tools/nxslt.shtml) written some years ago by Oleg Tkachenko**.

I am using an excellent XSLT IDE - the XSelerator. Unfortunately, at present the installation file for XSelerator isn't available online, but in case you can find it, I strongly recommend this XSLT development environment.